# Description of how the count of binary patches and their size is affected by noise?

Tags: binary-data, matrix, measurement-error, bias-variance-tradeoff, scale-invariance

In acoustics, signals can be represented as a matrix $M$ in time, frequency, and amplitude. Obviously the signal we want to describe is always superposed over other noise, $N$:

[image: road vehicle spectrogram]

One way to analyze long, repeated sequences of these signals is to binarize them: audible/inaudible. This can be done with a rectangular bound in time and frequency. If it helps, I see this as somewhat analogous to island shorelines - the terrain is continuous above and below the water, but it is helpful to binarize into land/ocean.

Over time it's become clear to me there is a trade-off between:

- how many discrete bounding rectangles are drawn (event count, $n$)
- how long each bounding rectangle extends in the time dimension (event duration, $d$)

It's also clear that both of these measures are dependent on the properties of $N$. (Equivalent to sea level rise in the island analogy - one island might separate into two and they would both be smaller. Islands could also be completely submerged.) We assume events occur randomly in time and have somewhat variable duration and magnitude.

---

I have empirical descriptions of how $n$ and $d$ change with $N$ for both human and computerized 'annotators', but I can't find a good theoretical description. I've started looking for insights from percolation theory, but I don't know what this type of problem would be called. I wonder, too, if this might be considered a form of bias-variance tradeoff?

**Is there a well-known approach to analyzing this problem of form, connectivity, and scale?** Rephrased, how is the event count $n$ and total duration of all events $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i$ expected to change in noise?

Comment: This is the domain of the field of [stochastic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_geometry).